# Scalable web application

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-dynamodb

We are building a social website using PHP (Zend Framework), MySQL, server running Apache.

There is a requirement where in dashboard the application will fetch data for different events (there are about 12 events) on which this dashboard for user will be updated. We expect the total no of users to be around 500k to 700k. While at one time on average about 20% users would be online (for peak time we expect 50% users to be online).

So the problem is the event data as per our current design will be placed in a MySQL database. I think running a few hundred thousands queries concurrently on MySQL wouldn't be a good idea even if we use Amazon RDS. So we are considering to use both DynamoDB (or Redis or any NoSQL db option) along with MySQL.

So the question is: Having data both in MySQL and any NoSQL database would give us this benefit to have this power of scalability for our web application? Or we should consider any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Having data both in MySQL and any NoSQL database" ? Duplicate your data ?

Comment: From having data both in MySQL and NoSQL means, I will be putting some relational data information in MySQL while data which would require more read / write operations such those showing on the user dashboard will be put in the NoSQL database.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to duplicate your data. One option is to use the ElastiCache that amazon provides to give your self in memory caching. This will get rid of your database calls and in a sense remove that bottleneck, but this can be very expensive.  If you can sacrifice rela time updates then you can get away with just slowing down the requests or caching data locally for the user. Say, cache the next N events if possible on the browser and display them instead of making another request to the servers.

If it has to be real time then look at the ElastiCache and then tweak with the scaling of how many of them you require to handle your estimated amount of traffic. There is no point in duplicating your data. Keep it in a single DB if it makes sense to keep it there, IE you have some relational information that you need and then also have a variable schema system then you can use both databases, but not to load balance them together.

I would also start to think of some bottle necks in your architecture and think of how well your application will/can scale in the event that you reach your estimated numbers.

Comment: Yes. I thought about the Amazon ElasticCache and I also feel it would be a bit more expensive. At the moment the data wouldn't be real time. It would be only when  the user loads the page it will  fetch the data for him for those 12 or so events associated with each user, but in future it could be made real time. The problem is it is possible at once there might be thousands of users online as mentioned in my problem so would it be a good idea to keep this data in MySQL only?

Comment: The solution I was thinking was to have data information at MySQL (some relational information as you mentioned) and the other in a NoSQL database and utilize both. So here I was thinking and studying to confirm this structure will scale and work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sean, there’s no need to duplicate the database. Have you thought about a something with auto-scalability, like [Xeround](http://xeround.com/). A solution like that can scale out automatically across several nodes when you have throughput peaks and later scale back in, so you don’t have to commit to a larger, more expansive instance just because of seasonal peaks.

Additionally, if I understand correctly, no code changes are required for this auto-scalability. So, I’d say that unless you need to duplicate your data on both MySQL and NoSQL DB’s for reasons other than scalability-related issues, go for a single DB with auto-scaling.